# Does drinking spoiled milk that has been boiled upset the GI tract?

Tags: pathology

With water, boiling will kill harmful pathogens. Does this also hold true for milk ? If it does not, what in the milk will continue to cause gatrointestinal distress ? Shouldn't boiling kill the harmful bacteria ?

I'd rather not get into a discussion whether animal milk should be consumed by humans. I am asking about a typical person who is not lactose intolerant and does not have any milk allergies.

Comment: Toxins could be produced by the bacteria that spoiled the milk that wouldn't be destroyed by boiling. Similarly, spores could be formed that are impervious to boiling as well.

Comment: @MattDMo If you would like to create an answer out of this I will mark this thread as answered. BTW out of curiosity, which toxins are they and how do spores upset the GI tract ?